# Error using generics on grails domain class

Tags: grails, grails-orm, hierarchy

I'm trying to create a generic abstract hierarchy implementation, the code is the following:

```
abstract class AbstractHierarchy<T> {
    T parent

    static hasMany = [children: T]

    static constraints = {
        parent(nullable: true)
    }

    static mapping = {
        tablePerHierarchy false
    }
}
```

Im getting this error:

```
AbstractHierarchy.groovy: -1: The class java.lang.Object refers to the class java.lang.Object and uses 1 parameters, but the referred class takes no parameters.
```

So the question is, Am I doing something wrong? is this supported by grails?
Searching the error I found this http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-11065
I'm using grails 2.3.7 by the way.

Answer (score 2):

On account of type erasure, I would expect that everywhere you are using `T` in your domain model, you might as well be using `Object`. So from GORM's perspective your model above is equivalent to

```
abstract class AbstractHierarchy {
    Object parent

    static hasMany = [children: Object]

    static constraints = {
        parent(nullable: true)
    }

    static mapping = {
        tablePerHierarchy false
    }
}
```

which I assume is not what you intended. So the moral of the story is: don't use generics to express relationships between your domain classes.

Comment: You can use an upper bound for the type parameter, e.g. `T extends AbstractHierarchy `. Then type erasure results in `AbstractHierarchy parent` and `static hasMany = [children: AbstractHierarchy]`. But I am not sure if you really want to create a class like this in the first place. Sounds too generic.